# Can I make a type assertion work with a typedef?

Tags: go

I have a custom type that allows me to work with an API more conveniently:

```golang
type Object map[string]interface{}
```

And this thing doesn't work:

```golang
var mockResponse = map[string]interface{}{"success": true}
resp, ok := mockResponse.(Object)
// ok = false
```

Can I do anything so `mockResponse.(Object)`'s `ok` is `true`? It's basically the same type...

Answer (score 7):

First of all, your "pseudo code" is a compile time error. You can't use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) on a value with concrete type (there's no point, a concrete type is a concrete type and nothing else), you may only use it on an interface value.

The example should be:

```
var mockResponse interface{} = map[string]interface{}{"success": true}
resp, ok := mockResponse.(Object)
```

Note that if `mockResponse` would be of type `map[string]interface{}`, then no type assertion would be needed, you could simply [convert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) it to `Object` like this:

```
var mockResponse = map[string]interface{}{"success": true}
obj := Object(mockResponse)
```

The [type definition](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations) creates a new, distinct type. And the type assertion to a concrete type only holds if you use the same concrete type.

What you may do is write a helper function which extracts `Object` from an interface value, which may handle both `map[string]interface{}` and also if the concrete type is `Object`:

```
func getObj(x interface{}) (o Object, ok bool) {
    switch v := x.(type) {
    case Object:
        return v, true
    case map[string]interface{}:
        return Object(v), true
    }
    return nil, false
}
```

Testing it:

```
resp, ok := getObj(map[string]interface{}{"success": true})
fmt.Println(resp, ok)

resp, ok = getObj(Object{"success": true})
fmt.Println(resp, ok)

resp, ok = getObj("invalid")
fmt.Println(resp, ok)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ASkOEKbHGs2)):

```
map[success:true] true
map[success:true] true
map[] false
```

Note: the above `getObj()` does not handle all possible cases where an `Object` could be "acquired" from the interface value.

For example if we'd have a type definition like this:

```
type Object2 Object
```

Passing a value of `Object2` to `getObj()`, an `Object` would not be extracted from it, even though a value of type `Object2` could be converted to `Object`:

```
resp, ok = getObj(Object2{"success": true})
fmt.Println(resp, ok) // map[] false
```

If you want to handle all possible cases where the concrete value is convertible to `Object`, you may use reflection:

```
var objType = reflect.TypeOf(Object{})

func getObj(x interface{}) (o Object, ok bool) {
    if v := reflect.ValueOf(x); v.Type().ConvertibleTo(objType) {
        o, ok = v.Convert(objType).Interface().(Object)
        return
    }
    return nil, false
}
```

Testing it (try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/KrPmqgoX13A)):

```
resp, ok = getObj(Object2{"success": true})
fmt.Println(resp, ok) // map[success:true] true
```

Using reflection is slower than a simple type assertion or type switch, so you can mix the 2 solutions:

```
func getObj(x interface{}) (o Object, ok bool) {
    // First try the trivial cases:
    switch v := x.(type) {
    case Object:
        return v, true
    case map[string]interface{}:
        return Object(v), true
    }

    // Then revert to reflection:
    if v := reflect.ValueOf(x); v.Type().ConvertibleTo(objType) {
        o, ok = v.Convert(objType).Interface().(Object)
        return
    }
    return nil, false
}
```